# Is there any way (keyboard shortcut) to shift an enitre piece of text?

Tags: support, feature-request, asking-questions

Okay I know I've worded the question horribly. We all know to make code visible in a box e.g:

\begin{document}

We have to shift it 4 spaces to the right so that it becomes:

```
\begin{document}
```

Is there any way to shift an entire group of text to the right instead of doing it line by line, like highlighting and then pressing the space bar, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at the line of icons above the answer box.

one of them is `{}` -- that indicates "code".

highlight the lines in your answer that you want presented as code,
then click on the `{}`.  done!

as noted by @JosephWright, Ctrl-K works as a shortcut after you've highlighted.

Comment: You sir/madam are my hero, (where were you two years ago when I first joined), thank you.

Comment: Perhaps add that the shortcut is Ctrl-K?

Comment: @JosephWright Does Ctrl-K exist? I wish I had known it before! It's extremely convenient!